# "Перегрузить" header в OkHttpClient

Tags: android, retrofit, token, dagger2, okhttp

Я использую `Dagger2`. Компонент соединения (`Network`) реализован как синглтон и внедряется в `Retrofit2`. Определяется объект этого компонента (`Network`) однажды, каждый раз при запуске приложения.

После этого приложение соединяется с веб сервисом для получения токена. С помощью этого токена происходит соединение с `API`.

Для удобства, я хотел положить этот токен в `header` моего объекта соединения (`Network`).

Но проблема в том что я использую `Dagger2` и этот объект является синглтоном т.е. его нельзя переопределить.

Как можно подложить объекту `Network` этот токен? Если нет, кто нибуть знает примеры использования `OkHttpClient` для авторизации с вложенным токеном в `header`.

По началу `phoneNumber` и `accessToken` пустые. Проинициализировав их в другом классе, я ложу их SharedPreferences и потом по идее они должны появится в `header` моего `Network` объекта. Но...

```
@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Client-Id", Constants.CONFIG.APP_NAME)
                    .addHeader("RE-Phone-Number", phoneNumber)
                    .addHeader("RE-Access-Token", accessToken);
            Request request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
}



@Provides
@PerApplication
Retrofit provideRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory,
                         RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxJavaCallAdapterFactory,
                         OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
            .build();
}
```

Другой класс `ApiModule` куда и инжектится `Retrofit`

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    CompanyService provideCompanyService(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(CompanyService.class);
    }
}
```

Это уже в классe `CompanyApplication` наследованный от `Application`

```
public void resolveDependencies() {
    mApiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
            .networkComponent(getNetworkComponent())
            .build();

    mUserComponent = DaggerUserComponent.builder()
            .networkComponent(getNetworkComponent())
            .build();
}

public NetworkComponent getNetworkComponent() {
    Map<String,String> map = getCredentialPrefs();
    return DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
            .networkModule(new NetworkModule(
                    HTTP.BASE_URL,
                    HTTP.API_KEY,
                    map.get(CONFIG.PREF_PHONE_NUMBER),
                    map.get(CONFIG.PREF_HASH)))
            .build();
}

public Map<String, String> getCredentialPrefs() {
    List<String> prefNames = new ArrayList<>();
    prefNames.add(CONFIG.PREF_PHONE_NUMBER);
    prefNames.add(CONFIG.PREF_HASH);
    Map<String, String> prefValues = Utils.getPrefs(getSharedPreferences(CONFIG.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), prefNames);
    return prefValues;
}
```

Comment: Что такое объект `Network`? Что, в итоге, вы инжектите для использования? Покажите весь код даггер-модуля.

Comment: @mit это компонент для связи  с сервисом. Этот OkHttpClient  используется Retrofit для дальнейшей работы с API

Comment: это понятно, вопрос в том где вы создаете `Retrofit` компонент? Вы его инжектите уже с этим `OkHttpClient` (т.е. внедряете `Retrofit` через `Dagger`) или инжектите `OkHttpClient` и создаете `Retrofit` отдельно?

Comment: @mit Да, первый вариант, я его инжектю уже с этом OkHttpCleint

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить хэдер к методу

```
@GET()
@Headers("@:auth")
Call<String> login(String login, String pass);
```

После чего навешать `interceptor`

```
Interceptor headerInterceptor = chain -> {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();

    List<String> annotations = original.headers().values("@");
    if (annotations.contains("auth")) {
        //Добавить хэдеры нужные
    }

    //Удалить ненужный
    builder.removeHeader("@");

    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае удалите

```
.addHeader("RE-Phone-Number", phoneNumber)
.addHeader("RE-Access-Token", accessToken);
```

в даггер-модуле.

Используйте возможности самого `Retrofit2`.

Примените аннотацию `@Header`:

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("RE-Phone-Number") String phoneNumber, 
                   @Header("RE-Access-Token") String accessToken);
```

И при вызове метода `API` добавляйте нужные значения.

Comment: Да, я делал так, пока не пришел к варианту который в вопросе. Хотел чтобы один раз написать токен в хидере для всего подключения и дальше использовать API. Но а так, нужно постоянно для каждого метода добавлять хидеры